# Is it legal to redefine wp_password_change_notification in a mu plugin?

Tags: php, functions, multisite

I am trying to add some logic to this function of when to alert the admin to a password change but no email is being sent at all. The codex says it needs to be declared in a plugin, so is this legal from a mu plugin or is there only specific locations this can be redeclared?

As it stands this is roughly my code but the mail never goes out:

```
if(!function_exists('wp_password_change_notification')){
    //die('I can get here');
    function wp_password_change_notification($user){
        //die('but never get here');
        //...code...
        wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] Password Lost/Changed'), $blogname), $message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the contents of a working example, placed in a php file in `wp-includes/mu-plugins/`. The email is sent when a user completes the password reset action after clicking the reset link in the email they receive.

```
<?php
if( ! function_exists( 'wp_password_change_notification' ) ){
    function wp_password_change_notification( &$user ){
        wp_mail( get_option('admin_email'), 'Test', 'test' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work from a mu plugin as well. (The codex is not very accurate, it should also be possible to override this function from a theme)

Comment: That makes sense. I have updated with my code which is very basic but it never gets inside the actual function?

Comment: There is no need to check if the function exists, it should not at the point mu plugins are loaded, but your code should work. I would remove that `if` but are you sure the file is included at all? and mail not going out might have different reasons that are not related to the fact that you are overriding the function

Comment: ok, maybe you just don't get on the correct execution path that generates the mail? Unless you have a misspelling that you fixed when copying the code to here there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

*Added code that I created and tested from the dashboard on my sandbox site. It's below and it will send an email on user password update.

You can edit the code anyway that you would like. Under the licensing GLP2 you are supposed to distribute the code with the same licensing as well. So if I make a WP Theme and distribute it, I am supposed to license my theme under GLP2. This does not stop me from charging money for my theme, or plugin, or anything else I make with Wordpress. To answer your question more directly, you are welcome to hack up your installation of Wordpress as much as you like. However, it is not recommended. You may need to update that install due to a security patch or any number of other future important updates and any work that you have done overwriting core WP code will be lost.

You can only overwrite a pluggable function once. I suggest you look http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-wordpress-pluggable-functions-and-their-usage--wp-30189 there to understand how pluggable functions are used. Possibly if you are having trouble overwriting the function, maybe another plugin is already doing it. Rather then overwrite code in the core, you would be safer removing the plugin, or adding a hook into the plugins code. Either way, you are well within your legal rights.

Wordpress provides developers with hooks so that we are able to dig our hands into the functionality of the core, without actually ever touching the core code. It is true that there are some functions that we haven't been able to hook into in the past. There is always the chance that there is a way to do something today, that could not be done last year with hooks. This leaves the WP code safe, and most importantly your code safe. Maybe something like 'profile_update' will do what you want. "This hook allows you to access data for a user immediately after their database information is updated. Two arguments are passed to functions using this hook: "user_id" (int) and "old_user_data" (object)." **UPDATE** The 'profile_update' hook doesn't work in the admin area (dashboard), so I found this hook and created a function to do what you need without overwriting anything.

```
/** This will hook into any profile change (tested from dashboard) */
add_action('personal_options_update', 'notify_admin_user_update');

function notify_admin_user_update ($user_id) {

    // Check to see that the password fields were used
    if ( !empty($_POST['pass1']) && !empty($_POST['pass2']) ) {
        // Make sure the 2 values match, or the password wouldn't have changed
        if ( $_POST['pass1'] === $_POST['pass2'] ) {

            // Get the user information
            $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
            $username = $user->user_login;
            $password = $_POST['pass1'];

            // Get the admin email address
            $admin_email = get_bloginfo('admin_email');

            // Create an email
            $subject = "User updated profile";
            $message = "Hello,\n Username {$username} is a good doobi and updated their password,\n"
                     . "Don't be a bad doobi and send their password in plaintext to your email.\n"
                     . "Like this... their new email is {$password}";

            // Ship it out!
            wp_mail($admin_email, $subject, $message );
        }
    }

}
```

Also, check out the add_action reference at Wordpress.org http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: The nettuts article is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time digging in the core and stack tracing to get my answer.

The answer is no. It is not possible as mu plugins run before pluggable.php. Since this is a pluggable function it cannot properly handle the use of this function. An added bit of information is that you cannot use a pluggable function with wp_mail in a mu plugin as this would return a php fatal not found if executed.

Comment: this is not correct. anything that overrides a pluggable function must run before pluggable, that's the only way it could possibly work. normal plugins also load before pluggable.php. I've just tested and conformed that an mu-plugin can override a pluggable function and that `wp_mail` works within that function. note that `wp_password_change_notification` is triggered after the password is reset, not when the password reset is requested.

Comment: @Milo I am unsure how this worked for you. When i simply called wp_mail at the top of the file i got a fatal. Can you provide sample code and I will give it a run.

Comment: you can't call `wp_mail` outside of an action or function that gets triggered before pluggable.php is loaded, but that's not the case inside `wp_password_change_notification`, where it works without issue.